# Looping some elements randomly in vue js / nuxt js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js

I get list elements from looping instagramPost, reviewPost, and tlcPost in order:

- Instagram Post1
- Instagram Post2
- Instagram Post3
- Review Post1
- Review Post2
- Review Post3
- Tlc Post1
- Tlc Post2
- Tlc Post3

But I want to show looping these elements randomly such as:
Instagram Post1

- Tlc Pos1
- Review Post1
- Instagram Post1
- Tlc Post2
- Review Post2
- Instagram Post3
- Tlc Pos3
- Review Posts3

  ```
   <div v-for="instagram in instagramPost" :key="instagram.id">
      <p>{{ instagram.title }}</p>
    </div>
    <div v-for="review in reviewPost" :key="review.id">
      <p>{{ review.title }}</p>
    </div>
    <div v-for="tlc in tlcPost" :key="tlc.id">
      <p>{{ tlc.title }}</p>
    </div>
  ```

```
<script>
export default {
async asyncData({$axios}) {
    const instagram  = await $axios.get("/tlc/instagram");
    const review = await $axios.get("/tlc/review");
    const tlcPost = await $axios.get("/tlc/tlc");
    
    return {
      instagramPost: instagram.data
      reviewPost: review.data
      tlcPost: tlcPost.data
    }
  },
data() {
    return {
      instagramPost: {},
      reviewPost: {},
      tlcPost: {}
    };
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming all three arrays have same structure you can merge them into single array and then shuffle it e.g

```
<script>
export default {
async asyncData({$axios}) {
    const instagram  = await $axios.get("/tlc/instagram");
    const review = await $axios.get("/tlc/review");
    const tlcPost = await $axios.get("/tlc/tlc");
    
    return {
      posts: [...instagram.data,...review.data,...tlcPost.data].sort(function(a,b){
        return Math.random() * 2-1;
      });
    }
  },
data() {
    return {
      posts: []
    };
}
</script>
```

then you can loop on that single array.
OR you can shuffle them any way you like as mentioned in this post.

[How to randomize (shuffle) a JavaScript array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2450954/how-to-randomize-shuffle-a-javascript-array)

Comment: my data is objects has different structure